# Asp.net C# : Error of system can find the file specified when using serialising json values (dictionary)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I have the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
values.Add("key1", "value1");
values.Add("key2", "value2");
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
```

but it's always throwing an exception:

> System can not find the file specified

Comment: Can you copy the actual error you are receiving? Nothing here looks incorrect

Comment: Unless `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` is missing from your project the error seems to have nothing to do with the code you posted.

Comment: i already import that Newtonsoft library. (using using Newtonsoft.Json;) so just to confirm do it need to add any file in reference. I installed this  Newtonsoft with nuget.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and It works well.

You should re-check some other cases:

1. Re-install library using.. `Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Reinstall`
2. Keep all the files from the bin-folder along with the executable, make sure the reference property "Copy Local" is set to true for `Newtonsoft.Json`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following

1. remove the reference for NewtonSoft from your project
2. uninstall it if its installed from under 'Manage Nuget Packages' of your project
3. Install latest newtonsoft

Run your code again and it should work

**why does this error occur**

Normally when you copy the project from another system, the referenced are there in the project files but the files themselves do not exist. You can restore the nuget packages to resolve the issue.